# Format of complex number in Python

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I am wondering about the way Python (3.3.0) prints complex numbers.  I am looking for an explanation, not a way to change the print.

Example:

```
>>> complex(1,1)-complex(1,1)
0j
```

Why doesn't it just print "0"?  My guess is: to keep the output of type complex.

Next example:

```
>>> complex(0,1)*-1
(-0-1j)
```

Well, a simple "-1j" or "(-1j)" would have done.  And why "-0"??  Isn't that the same as +0?  It doesn't seem to be a rounding problem:

```
>>> (complex(0,1)*-1).real == 0.0
True
```

And when the imaginary part gets positive, the -0 vanishes:

```
>>> complex(0,1)
1j
>>> complex(0,1)*-1
(-0-1j)
>>> complex(0,1)*-1*-1
1j
```

Yet another example:

```
>>> complex(0,1)*complex(0,1)*-1
(1-0j)
>>> complex(0,1)*complex(0,1)*-1*-1
(-1+0j)
>>> (complex(0,1)*complex(0,1)*-1).imag
-0.0
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Regarding the `0j` part, it's common practice in python that `eval(repr(x)) == x`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It prints `0j` to indicate that it's still a `complex` value. You can also type it back in that way:

```
>>> 0j
0j
```

The rest is probably the result of the magic of [IEEE 754 floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which makes a distinction between 0 and -0, the so-called [signed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero). Basically, there's a single bit that says whether the number is positive or negative, regardless of whether the number happens to be zero. This explains why `1j * -1` gives something with a negative zero real part: the positive zero got multiplied by -1.

-0 is required by the standard to compare equal to +0, which explains why `(1j * -1).real == 0.0` still holds.

The reason that Python still decides to print the -0, is that in the complex world these make a difference for branch cuts, for instance in [the `phase` function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/cmath.html#cmath.phase):

```
>>> phase(complex(-1.0, 0.0))
3.141592653589793
>>> phase(complex(-1.0, -0.0))
-3.141592653589793
```

This is about the imaginary part, not the real part, but it's easy to imagine situations where the sign of the real part would make a similar difference.

Comment: I just want to add to this answer, that all described cases are valid and python works as expected. You can find special test case with all representations relative to IEEE 754: `Lib/tests/test_complex.py`, `test_negative_zero_repr_str`

Comment: Just tested and it appears you're correct about `-0`: `>>> 0j.real.hex()`
`'0x0.0p+0'`
`>>> (0j*-1).real.hex()`
`'-0x0.0p+0'`

Comment: I confirm the `-0` part: `print(0.0*-1)` prints "`-0.0`". And since `complex` type in Python is a pair of _float_ numbers, it doesn't matter whether you specified the fractional part or not.

Comment: The `repr` is wrong to use `'(-0-1j)'`. It needs to be `'-0.0-1j'` for `eval(repr(1j*-1))` to return the original value. `-0` is just `int(0)`.

Comment: Figured out the last part too, why we still want to print -0.

Comment: Is there any way to test the imaginary part of a complex number and see if it's a negative or positive zero?

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the Python source code itself.

I'll work with one of your examples. Let

```
a = complex(0,1)
b = complex(-1, 0)
```

When you do`a*b` you're calling [this function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/399e59ad0a70/Objects/complexobject.c#l42):

```
real_part = a.real*b.real - a.imag*b.imag
imag_part = a.real*b.imag + a.imag*b.real
```

And if you do that in the python interpreter, you'll get

```
>>> real_part
-0.0
>>> imag_part
-1.0
```

From IEEE754, you're getting a [negative zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), and since [that's not +0](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/399e59ad0a70/Objects/complexobject.c#l345), you get the parens and the real part when printing it.

```
if (v->cval.real == 0. && copysign(1.0, v->cval.real)==1.0) {
    /* Real part is +0: just output the imaginary part and do not
       include parens. */
...
else {
    /* Format imaginary part with sign, real part without. Include
       parens in the result. */
...
```

I guess (but I don't know for sure) that the rationale comes from the importance of that sign when calculating with elementary complex functions (there's a reference for this in the wikipedia article on signed zero).

Answer (score 3):

- `0j` is an [imaginary literal](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals) which indeed indicates a complex number rather than an integer or floating-point one.
- The `+-0` ("signed zero") is a result of Python's conformance to [IEEE 754 floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) since in Python, [`complex` is by definition a pair of *floating point* numbers](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric). Due to the latter, there's no need to print or specify zero fraction parts for a `complex` too.
- The `-0` part is *printed* in order to accurately represent the contents [as `repr()`'s documentation demands](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#repr) (`repr()` is implicitly called whenever an operation's result is output to the console).
- Regarding the question **why `(-0+1j) = 1j` but `(1j*-1) = (-0+1j)`.** 
  Note that `(-0+0j)` or `(-0.0+0j)` aren't single complex numbers but *expressions* - an `int`/`float` added to a `complex`. To compute the result, first the first number is converted to a `complex` (`-0`-> `(0.0,0.0)` since integers don't have signed zeros, `-0.0`-> `(-0.0,0.0)`). Then its `.real` and `.imag` are *added* to the corresponding ones of `1j` which are `(+0.0,1.0)`. The result is `(+0.0,1.0)` :^) . To construct a complex directly, use `complex(-0.0,1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about str/repr. But here a "print(0j*-1)" still returns "(-0+0j)", so it behaves the same. Furthermore, *if* python so strictly clings to the IEEE standard with its repr(), why does a "print(-0+0j)" return "0j"?

Comment: 2cxxl: `(-0+0j)` isn't a single complex number but an expression - an integer added to a complex. When the result is computed, `-0` is converted to a complex and added to its `.real` which is `0`. The result is `+0` :^)

Comment: Since my assumption about `str()` proved false in this case, I wiped it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the first question is concerned: if it just printed `0` it would be mathematically correct, but you wouldn't know you were dealing with a `complex` object vs an `int`. As long as you don't specify `.real` you will always get a J component.

I'm not sure why you would ever get `-0`; it's not technically incorrect `(-1 * 0 = 0)` but it's  syntactically odd.

As far as the rest goes, it's strange that it isn't consistent, however none are technically correct, just an artifact of the implementation.