# Square root of complex numbers in python

Tags: python, math, complex-numbers

I have run across some confusing behaviour with square roots of complex numbers in python.  Running this code:

```
from cmath import sqrt
a = 0.2
b = 0.2 + 0j
print(sqrt(a / (a - 1)))
print(sqrt(b / (b - 1)))
```

gives the output

```
0.5j
-0.5j
```

A similar thing happens with

```
print(sqrt(-1 * b))
print(sqrt(-b))
```

It appears these pairs of statements should give the same answer?

Comment: According to [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) you are correct. The first pair ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(0.2+%2F+(0.2+-+1))) and [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(+(0.2%2B0i)+%2F+(+(0.2%2B0i)+-1+)))) both should be `0.5i`, and the second pair ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(-1+*+(0.2+%2B+0i))) and [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(-1+*+(0.2+%2B+0i)))) should both be `0.447214... i`. The source for `cmath.sqrt()` is [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/cmathmodule.c#l732)...

Comment: Both answers are correct, the question is why it returns different conjugates.

Comment: FWIW the behavior appears the same in 2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: There are simply multiple solutions to a complex root.

Comment: @tzaman ...And if it's defined somewhere which one Python should return. If it's not defined, Python has right to choose any.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both answers (`+0.5j` and `-0.5j`) are correct, since they are [complex conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) -- i.e. the real part is identical, and the imaginary part is sign-flipped.

Looking at the [code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/cmathmodule.c#l732) makes the behavior clear - the imaginary part of the result always has the *same sign* as the imaginary part of the input, as seen in lines 790 and 793:

```
r.imag = copysign(d, z.imag);
```

Since `a/(a-1)` is `0.25` which is implicitly `0.25+0j` you get a positive result; `b/(b-1)` produces `0.25-0j` (for some reason; not sure why it doesn't result in `0.25+0j` tbh) so your result is similarly negative.

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387782/format-of-complex-number-in-python) has some useful discussion on the same issue.

Comment: `a / (a - 1)` is `-0.25`. Converting it to complex gives you `-0.25+0j`. With b, you get `-0.25-0j`.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html#cmath.sqrt) also specifies that the branch cut is chosen to be along a ray from 0 to -∞, which would give the observed behavior. It's interesting that `b/(b-1)` gives a negative zero for the imaginary component, though.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, that's pretty weird, I'm not sure why it does that. Simply typing `1-0j` in as a literal into IDLE produces `1+0j` as a value. Interestingly, `-0j` by itself produces `-0-0j` though.

Comment: @tzaman: That's a nasty edge case in the syntax. A complex number with a negative zero imaginary component gets `repr`esented as `0.2-0j`, but the expression `0.2-0j` is actually a subtraction of `0.2` and `0j`. The subtraction produces a *positive* zero imaginary component, because `0j - 0j` is *positive* `0j`. It's [come up](http://bugs.python.org/issue25839) a few times on the bug tracker. There's a related problem where negative zero real components aren't visible in the `repr` output at all.

Comment: @user2357112 that's fascinating, thanks for the link!

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is a bit misleading in my opinion. Every complex number has two square roots, and it's true that ***if*** a complex number x is a negative real number, ***then*** its two square roots are going to be pure imaginary and complex conjugates; but in general, the two square roots of a complex number are ***opposites***, not conjugates. In fact, the two square roots of a complex number x are conjugates ***if and only if*** x is a negative real number (and that's because the opposite of a pure imaginary is its conjugate).

Answer (score 2):

I can answer why this is happening, but not why the behavior was chosen.

```
a/(a - 1)
```

evaluates to 0.2/-0.8 which is -0.25, which is converted to a complex number by `cmath.sqrt`, while

```
b/(b - 1)
```

evaluates to (0.2+0j)/(-0.8+0j) which is (-0.25-0j), which is converted to a complex number with a negative complex component.

For a simpler example,

```
cmath.sqrt(0j) == 0j
cmath.sqrt(-0j) == -0j
```