# Bogus parsing/eval of complex literals

Tags: python, parsing, ieee-754, complex-numbers

When evaluating complex numbers, python likes to fiddle the signs.

```
>>> -0j
(-0-0j)
>>> (-0-0j)
0j
```

Why?

*nb:* I noticed it when reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36584466/674039) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that Python doesn't parse complex numbers such as `(-0-0j)` as literals, they are actually parsed as an expression:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('(-0-0j)'))
'Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=UnaryOp(op=USub(), operand=Num(n=0)), op=Sub(), right=Num(n=0j)))])'
```

So, this is not a complex literal but a *reflected* subtraction of a complex and an integer.

```
>>> -0-0j
0j
>>> (0j).__rsub__((0).__neg__())
0j
```

The int part is coerced to having a 0j complex component, and then we lose the expected [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) from the result because of the subtraction of the complex components.  The result of `0j - 0j` should have positive sign, as [IEEE 754-2008](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4610935) dictates.

This is arguably a parser issue, because the sign of the zero can influence the solutions of equations.  However, the issue has been [repeatedly](http://bugs.python.org/issue22548) [raised](http://bugs.python.org/issue25839) and [closed](http://bugs.python.org/issue17336) on the python tracker as 'not a bug', so it doesn't look like that behaviour will be going away any time soon.  The reliable way to initialize complex numbers when you care about signed zeros is by calling the [`complex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=complex#complex) built-in:

```
>>> 0-0j
0j
>>> 0+0j
0j
>>> complex(0., -0.)
-0j
>>> complex(0., +0.)
0j
```