# Why/how do -1j and 0-1j become different strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Why and how are `-1j` and `0 - 1j` turned into different strings?

```
>>> a = -1j
>>> b = 0 - 1j
>>> a
(-0-1j)
>>> b
-1j
```

They're the same value of the same type:

```
>>> a == b
True
>>> type(a), type(b), type(a) is type(b)
(<class 'complex'>, <class 'complex'>, True)
```

But both `str` and `repr` turn them into different strings:

```
>>> str(a), str(b)
('(-0-1j)', '-1j')
>>> repr(a), repr(b)
('(-0-1j)', '-1j')
```

Why and how does that happen?

Note: This is in Python 3.6.4. In Python 2.7.14 they're both turned into `'-1j'`.

Comment: Hmm, four downvotes? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Maybe the -0 in `a`, although I doubt the downvoters were reading that carefully.

Comment: If the above question is _not_ a duplicate, it at least has some good discussion about the issue.  I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388276/3483203) answer might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` has a real component of `-0.0`, while `b` has a real component of `0.0`. The `0.0` is omitted from the string representation.

`-1j` is treated as `-(1j)`, where `1j` has a real component of `0.0`. That real component gets negated.

In `0 - 1j`, the real components of both sides are 0, and the subtraction produces a real component of 0.

On Python 2, I think `-1j` probably hits the same special case used to make `-2147483648` or `-9223372036854775808` (platform-dependent) evaluate to an int instead of a long. The special-case handling seems to result in a real component of `0.0`.

Comment: Ah, right, `-0.0` is a thing. That explains it. Still weird and inconvenient. Maybe I'll just add zero to get rid of it... both `-1j + 0` and `0 + -1j` get turned into the nicer `'-1j'`.