# Why printing same complex negative number gives strange output?

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I am new to python so my question may sound silly. Trying to print some complex numbers.

```
t1 = 5j
t2 = -5j
print(t1)
print(t2)
```

This prints:

```
5j
(-0-5j)
```

Can someone please explain what is the rule/logic behind this formation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format of complex number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387782/format-of-complex-number-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print function is doing its best to print a mathematical equation to represent the number, which is then surrounded by parenthesis. In the second case, the notation is the real number added to the imaginary component. Further reading [here](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/math/python-math-exercise-32.php).